# -bash: npm: command not found, WHY?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, terminal, npm-install

While experimenting with oh-my-zsh and zsh, I managed to delete terminal com.apple.terminal.*, .bash_profile.

After fixing everything, my terminal is not recognising any command.
When I type npm, it shows:

> -bash: npm: command not found

So does for all other installed packages like dotnet core.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Probably you just need to edit your `$PATH` variable and set again the paths.

You could check your current `$PATH` by doing:

```
echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}
```

That will list your existing paths, and probably there will be missing some  `$HOME/paths`

Is that the case just add them based on your requirements, in macOS for `node/npm` would be something like:

```
export PATH="$HOME/node_modules/.bin:$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$HOME/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$PATH"
```

This will give priority to the files located in `$HOME/node_modules/.bin`

In case you uninstalled or removed node you could try this:

```
brew update && brew install node
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response I guess I misunderstood my problem has documented again here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140386/npm-command-of-recognise-on-terminal-after-after-messing-bash-profile

Comment: did you try what wrote in the answer?

Comment: Yes I did, and nothing changed.

Comment: then maybe you just removed node, try to install it again

Comment: I have this heavy base of packages which I don't want to uninstall\install again :(

Comment: try this `brew upgrade node` that will just ensure that at least you have nmp